# Getting Emacs to use pdflatex

Tags: emacs, latex, pdflatex

How can I configure Emacs to run pdflatex rather than latex on a LaTeX file when I type C-c C-f (tex-file)?

Comment: Probably next time you'd like to post such a question at TeX.SE :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by setting latex-run-command; see the [the emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/TeX-Print.html#TeX-Print). Something like this in your .emacs should do it:

(setq latex-run-command "pdflatex")

Answer (score 9):

You can temporarily switch AucTeX to pdf mode with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. To make this change permanent set

```
(TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

in your `~/.emacs` file.

Comment: very useful answer.... but NB ctrl-c ctrl-t ctrl-p ( not ctrl-c t p )

Answer (score 4):

Should it not be

```
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
```

in `.emacs`?

My version of emacs (GNU 24) complains when I just have `(TeX-PDF-mode t)`.

(Or maybe this is because I am using [AucTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/), which is awesome BTW.)

Answer (score 1):

After trying several approaches, the one that worked for me (also for AucTeX) was

`M-x customize-group` for `TeX-command`, and rewriting "Latex Command" to pdflatex.

(Changing the viewer to open the pdf wasn't even necessary, it just worked.)

(idea from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63736/how-to-change-auctex-latex-compile-command-using-emacs-23).)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use pdflatex with Auctex and `(TeX-PDF-mode t)` or `(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)` in my `~/.emacs` didn't work, so here is what I found out:

There is a variable and a function with the same name: `TeX-PDF-mode`. One can either set the variable directly with `(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)` or use the function `(TeX-PDF-mode t)`. But the variable is not only buffer local, but [**automatically** buffer local](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal.html#Intro-to-Buffer_002dLocal).

Buffer local means there is a default value for the variable and every buffers can have a local binding. Changes to the variable in buffers without a local binding change the default value. Changes to the variable in buffers with a local binding affect only the local binding.

Automatically buffer local means that every change to the variable becomes automatically buffer local, if there wasn't already a local binding it gets created. There is no way to change the default value with `setq`, one has to use `setq-default`.

So, using `(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)` or `(TeX-PDF-mode t)` in `~/.emacs` should have no effect on yet to be created buffers. One has to use either `(setq-default TeX-PDF-mode t)`, or better the provided function **`(TeX-global-PDF-mode t)`**.